# Move Ubuntu partition to another drive and resize?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

The Ubuntu installer messed up and my Ubuntu partition is now 50GB and on `/dev/sdc`. I want it to be the 230GB free space on `/dev/sda`.

I'm a bit worried about this since I don't want to lose any data from `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdc`, but I also can't live on 50GB and I can't have this eating up 50GB from `/dev/sdc`.

**Edit**: To clarify, I don't have enough space on `/dev/sdc` to resize before moving, I'd have to do it after.

Comment: It is almost always easier to just do a new install. Then copy just /home and maybe some system wide settings in /etc, if you manually edited any of those (like grub settings). If you installed lots of apps you can export list & reinstall that. Just like restoring from you backup, or test you have good backups. With new gpt partitions you cannot image copy just a partition. And if you copy files, you also have to change UUIDs in all the places UUID is used as you are in a new partition. I also prefer separating / (root) & data, either /home or /data partition.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure whether I understood the problem completely, but you could do the following: Create a new partition on /dev/sda (with gparted) that is big enough for your liking, mark it as bootable. Remove the boot flag from the /sdc partition that currently has it.  Mount the new partition, copy your Ubuntu installation to this partition. Reboot. Ubuntu should now be running from the new copy on the /dev/sda partition, so you can unmount the old partition on /dev/sdc. Do that, delete it (with gparted) and use the free space in whichever way you want.

Comment: Thank you! I'm in my windows part right now waiting for an install to finish, so I can't yet but when I've tried this I'll get back to you.

Comment: Hey, I've been doing this but now I'm stuck at copying the files to the new partition.

"Error while copying, the folder efi cannot be handled because you do not have permission to read it"

Comment: `sudo cp -r /boot/efi/ /path/to/mounted/partition/boot/`

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to stick with me for a second cause im a total noob, I'm not sure I'm doing this command correctly but I entered it as "sudo cp -r /boot/efi/ /dev/sda5/" and I got "failed to access '/dev/sda5/': Not a directory"

Comment: `/path/to/mounted/partion` means the location in the directory tree where /dev/sda5 is mounted. You get that via `mount | grep sda5`.

Comment: "/dev/sda5 on /media/londen/New Volume type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)"

that's the entire output. Should I paste that entire thing into the command?

Comment: The first line shows you the position in directory tree. That is `/media/londen/New Volume`. For the command, you have to escape the blank in the path, so the command would be `sudo cp -r /boot/efi /media/londen/New\ Volume/boot/`.

Comment: Okay, NOW we seem to be getting somewhere, but I don't think it's quite there yet. This did indeed copy something to the new part, but I don't think it's right. It put a folder called "boot" in there. Just a folder called boot. Whereas aren't we trying to get everything from my linux part into there?

Comment: Yes, this command only copied that part that was left out from the earlier one. The folder `/media/londen/New Volume/boot/`should contain two subdirs, though, one called `efi`, one called `grub` and a number of files. Are you sure this is not the case?

Comment: No grub dir, just efi. And, earlier I couldn't copy anything from the part, efi was just the only one I reported to use as an example. I need to copy everything from /dev/sdc2.

Comment: Ah, I understand. You need to copy everything using sudo. Use the following commands: `sudo cp -a /bin /boot /cdrom /etc /home /lib /lib32 /lib64 /opt /root /sbin /usr /var /media/londen/New\ Volume/` then `cd /media/londen/New\ Volume; sudo mkdir media mnt snap srv tmp`. This copies the "filled" directories and creates the directories that are only filled at runtime.

Comment: After this, I should be clear to boot into the new part on /dev/sda and nuke this 50GB accidental part on /dev/sdc, right?

Comment: I'd think so, but that might be wishful thinking without having your system there for inspection. In any case don't nuke anything until you're sure you don't need it any longer! I compiled the list of directories to be copied from my own relatively unchanged default installation, but do compare whether you might have anything on your system that is not on the list.

Comment: Smart, yeah. So, I just had another thought which is that if I try to boot in now won't grub be launching the old ubuntu on /dev/sdc? I'd probably need to fiddle with grub somehow to get the Ubuntu option to open /dev/sda5 right?

Comment: I'd expect that since you've change the boot flag on the partitions, BIOS/UEFI would look for a grub install on /dev/sda5, find it and boot.

Comment: Okay, did a small bit of googling and `sudo OS prober` followed by `sudo update-grub` did the trick.